# Recaptcha Response PHP 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php

I'm trying to check with Ajax a ReCaptcha V2 from Google. The problem is I keep getting error 500. This is my code.

```
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response, true);

$success = $responseKeys['success'];

if(!$success) return json_encode(['status' => 'CAPTCHA_ERROR']);

sendMail($request);
```

$url is fine I double checked and if I do this instead:

```
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response, true);

return $responseKeys;
```

And I `console.log` it in the browser, I get the right response:

```
{"success":true,"challenge_ts":"2017-10-05T03:30:18Z","hostname":"mysite.com"}
```

Comment: nope I'm using PHP 7, I'm using the "new" array syntax all over my project with no problems.

Comment: Okay, so what does the error log say? It should tell you the reason. A `500` is about as useful as the `check engine` light. Luckily your server has the computer included so you don't need to bring it to the mechanic.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP and the php_error_log.log file is missing, only have error.log but it doesn't say anything about this errors I'm having

Comment: Look at `phpinfo()`, is your error log `error.log` or `php_error_log.log`? Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: in phpinfo(), log_errors is ON and error_log is like this:  C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log

Comment: I tried everything, creating the file, deleting it, restarting the server, using .log extension, using .txt extension, using another file name, tweaking php.ini, no way to log anything